# Python ImportError on Windows8.1 with module

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library

I believe I have this problem because python is not finding the module installed on my machine and I'm not sure what the best way to debug this is.

First off, I know I have the module installed. If I do `pip freeze`

I get:

```
Pillow==2.9.0
praw==2.1.20
requests==2.5.3
six==1.9.0
update-checker==0.11
```

However, when I try to run the following code, it tell me that there is no module named Pillow

```
import os
from Pillow import Image


def extractFrames(inGif, outFolder):
    frame = Image.open(inGif)
    nframes = 0
    while frame:
        frame.save( '%s/%s-%s.gif' % (outFolder, os.path.basename(inGif), nframes ) , 'GIF')
        nframes += 1
        try:
            frame.seek( nframes )
        except EOFError:
            break;
    return True


extractFrames('donkey.gif', 'output')
```

I've programmed a lot in node.js so I'm used to package dependency there, but the system of pip is pretty foreign to and I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

```
from PIL import Image
```

Pillow is a fork of PIL and for backwards compatibility they kept the import name PIL. (Kind of weird).

Comment: That fixed it! I thought it was an install problem haha. Thanks!